# Swift: Three prototype cells in TableviewController won't view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I want to create three cells in a tableview controller and I added three  prototype cells in storyboard it doesn't crash but it view an empty tableview.

```
 super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    let nib1 = UINib(nibName: "one", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib1, forCellReuseIdentifier: "one")
    let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "two", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "two")
    let nib3 = UINib(nibName: "three", bundle: nil)

    tableView.registerNib(nib3, forCellReuseIdentifier: "three")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        var cell:UITableViewCell!

```
    switch (indexPath.row){
    case 0 :
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("one") as! one
        cell.textLabel?.text = "book1"
        break;
    case 1:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("two") as! two
          cell.textLabel?.text = "book2"
        break;
    case 2 :
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("three") as! three
          cell.textLabel?.text = "book3"

    default:
        break;

    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Comment: When you ask for help, please make sure to ask a clear question.

Comment: sorry what is not clear

Comment: What is your question? You have only stated your problem.

Comment: I did everything right but none of the three cells are visible in the simulator without crash or errors

Comment: an empty tableview viewed only without data

Comment: the actual question is why the three cells text won't appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you'll always want exactly 3 cells to show in your table view, you should use the "Static Cells" style of `UITableView`. You can set this in the Storyboard if you select the appropriate `UITableView` and look in the Attributes Inspector.

Then, drag out the correct number of cells and configure them in the Storyboard. Connect each cell to an `IBOutlet` if you need to manipulate them or their contents programmatically.

Note that, since static table views are only allowed in a `UITableViewController`, you may need to change the class that contains the code you included in your question.